# undirected Graph adjacency list implementation using C

Tags: graph, linked-list

Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 5

typedef struct list
{
    int data;
    struct list * next;//self referenced structure
}slist;

void displayList(slist * start)
{
    slist * temp;
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        printf("Empty Linked List");
        return;
    }

    for(temp=start;temp!=NULL;temp=temp->next)
        printf("%d ",temp->data);

    return;
}

void insertLast(slist * * start,slist * node)
{
    slist * temp;
    if(start==NULL){
        (* start)=node;
        return;
    }
    temp=(* start);

    while((temp->next)!= NULL)
        temp=temp->next;

    temp->next=node;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    //slist * node;
    char Ans;

    /*printf("Write the number of vertices\n");
    scanf("%d",&N);*/
    slist * start[N];
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        start[i]=NULL;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<N;j++)
        {
            printf("Is there a connection between V[%d] and V[%d]\n",(i+1),(j+1));
            scanf(" %c",&Ans);

            if(Ans=='y'||Ans=='Y')
            {
                slist * node1=(slist *)malloc(sizeof(slist));
                node1->data=(j+1); node1->next=NULL;
                insertLast(&start[i],node1);enter code here

                slist * node2=(slist *)malloc(sizeof(slist));
                node2->data=(i+1); node2->next=NULL;
                insertLast(&start[j],node2);
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        displayList(start[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The above code is showing segmentation fault at the line where `while((temp->next)!=NULL)` is written whereas while creation of linked lists, the same `insertLast` worked just fine. What is the fault in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Your program crashed as you are checking if `start` is NULL or not. But that does not guarantee that `*start` is also not NULL. In such situation, `temp` gets NULL and in `while` loop `temp->next` actually trying to access `next` element of NULL pointer and that is why the crash.

Changing this line -

```
if(start==NULL)
```

to

```
if(*start==NULL)
```

in `insertLast()` will fix the crash.

I also recommend to use a debugger like `gdb` to debug such issues.